# Yii2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, yii2, bundle

MyAssetset:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset'
    ];
}
```

`MyMain.php` has register this asset:

```
AppAsset::register($this);
```

in my test.php use jquery

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Has this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: You have to include jQuery before calling it

Comment: could be you are including more time  .. the asset .. try comment AppAsset::register($this);  .. (the asset are managed  by Yii directly at bootstrap)

Comment: I have doubt Is JqueryAsset already include jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use javascript scripts via assets or with method registerJs here is example

```
<?php $this->registerJs('$(function () { $(\'#datetimepicker1\').datetimepicker();});', View::POS_END); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default AppAset.php for yii2 (this sample is in for backend )

```
  <?php
  /**
   * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
   * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
   * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
   */

  namespace backend\assets;

  use yii\web\AssetBundle;

  /**
   * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
   * @since 2.0
   */
  class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
  {
      public $basePath = '@webroot';
      public $baseUrl = '@web';
      public $css = [
          'css/site.css',
      ];
      public $js = [
      ];
      public $depends = [
          'yii\web\YiiAsset',
          'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
      ];
  }
```

As you can see there is  no refernce to jquery because this is normally managed by yii2  Asset bundle

try using this content for Appset.php  (eventually mwith the namespace you need) withour referring to other jquery asset and withour register  .. 
This mnormally work in advanced template